# capture image from camera and send it directly to server

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-camera-intent

I'm trying to write a small code that allows me to send picture directly after taking it from the camera, I mean when I take picture from the camera, this picture will be sent directly to the server without to store in my phone or in the sdcard, So I made this Code but I dont know if it is correct, because Actually it shows me much message error but I don't know where is the problem or if someone can tell me where can I find similar code,

```
// Upload Direct From Camera
camButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent_gallery = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent_gallery.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, SERVER_URL + "uploadFromCamera.php" );
        startActivityForResult(intent_gallery, SELECT_IMAGE);
    }
});
...

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri       = data.getData();
            String selectedImagePath   = getPath( selectedImageUri );
            String url                 = SERVER_URL + "uploadFromCamera.php";

            if ( selectedImagePath != null ) {
                //Send to server
            }
        }
    }           
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String result = null;
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){;
       int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
       result = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the error/LogCat you get?

Comment: -Failure delivering result ResultInfo{ request=1, result=-1, data=Intent} to activity

Comment: ...Caused by NullPointerException at...(this line :Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);)

Comment: It doesn't look like you define `uri`.

Comment: Icheck it again but it is empty, Why?

Answer (score 6):

This code helps to upload a image to TomCat server.

Android app

```
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.util.Base64;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
    import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
    import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ProgressDialog prgDialog;
    String encodedString;
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    String imgPath, fileName;
    Bitmap bitmap, lesimg;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
    private static int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    private static String TIME_STAMP="null";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        prgDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {

        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    }
    public void dispatchTakePictureIntent(View view) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            lesimg=imageBitmap;
            String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

            String hjkl=currentDateTimeString.replaceAll(" ", "_");
            String hiop=hjkl.replaceAll(":", "-");
            TIME_STAMP=hiop;
            fileName=TIME_STAMP+".jpeg";
            params.put("filename", fileName);
        }
    }


    public void uploadImage(View v) {
        encodeImagetoString();

    }


    public void encodeImagetoString() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

            protected void onPreExecute() {

            };

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
                options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 3;

                bitmap=lesimg;
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream); 
                byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();

                encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
                return "";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                prgDialog.setMessage("Calling Upload");
                prgDialog.show();

                params.put("image", encodedString);

                triggerImageUpload();
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }

    public void triggerImageUpload() {
        makeHTTPCall();
    }

    public void makeHTTPCall() {
        prgDialog.setMessage("Invoking JSP");   
        prgDialog.show();
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        client.post("http://Your Ip Address or Localhost:8080/ImageUploadWebApp/uploadimg.jsp",
                params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String response) {

                        prgDialog.hide();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                            String content) {

                        prgDialog.hide();

                        if (statusCode == 404) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Requested resource not found",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        else if (statusCode == 500) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Something went wrong at server end",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error Occured \n Most Common Error: \n1. Device not connected to Internet\n2. Web App is not deployed in App server\n3. App server is not running\n HTTP Status code : "
                                            + statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

        if (prgDialog != null) {
            prgDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Android xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLoadPicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:onClick="dispatchTakePictureIntent"
        android:text="Click Picture" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:onClick="uploadImage"
        android:text="Upload" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Server Part
Create a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse and run it using TomCat Server

WebApp

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;






public class ManipulateImage {
     public static byte[] convertStringtoImage(String encodedImageStr,    String fileName) {
         byte[] imageByteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedImageStr);
            try {

                 // URL url = new URL("http://www.amrood.com/index.htm?language=en#j2se");

                imageByteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedImageStr); 

                // Write Image into File system - Make sure you update the path
                FileOutputStream imageOutFile = new FileOutputStream("C:/Some file Path" + fileName);
                imageOutFile.write(imageByteArray);

                imageOutFile.close();

                System.out.println("Image Successfully Stored");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
                System.out.println("Image Path not found" + fnfe);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("Exception while converting the Image " + ioe);
            }
            return imageByteArray;

        }
     public static String[]  display(){

         File folder = new File("C:/Some file Path");
         File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
         String [] k = new String[listOfFiles.length];
         Arrays.fill(k,"none");

             for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
               if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                 System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
                 k[i]="File " + listOfFiles[i].getName();
               } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                 System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
               }

             }
             return k;
     }

}
```

Servlet

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class DisplayImageServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements javax.servlet.Servlet {
static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
String image_name = "";
ResourceBundle props = null;
String filePath = "";
private static final int BUFSIZE = 100;
private ServletContext servletContext;
public DisplayImageServlet() {
super();
}
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
System.out.println("FROM SERVLET");
sendImage(getServletContext(), request, response);
}
public void sendImage(ServletContext servletContext,
HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
this.servletContext = servletContext;
String reqUrl = request.getRequestURL().toString();
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(reqUrl, "/");
int noOfTokens = tokens.countTokens();
String tokensString[] = new String[noOfTokens];
int count = 0;
while (tokens.hasMoreElements()) {
tokensString[count++] = (String) tokens.nextToken();
}
String folderName = tokensString[noOfTokens - 2];
image_name = tokensString[noOfTokens - 1];
filePath = "/" + folderName + "/" + image_name;
String fullFilePath = "D:/AndroidStudioProjects" + filePath;
System.out.println("FULL PATH :: "+fullFilePath);

doDownload(fullFilePath, request, response);
}
private void doShowImageOnPage(String fullFilePath,
HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException {
response.reset();
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
response.setContentType("image/tiff");
byte[] image = getImage(fullFilePath);
OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(image);
outputStream.close();
}
private void doDownload(String filePath, HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
File fileName = new File(filePath);
int length = 0;
ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

ServletContext context = servletContext;
String mimetype = context.getMimeType(filePath);
response.setContentType((mimetype != null) ? mimetype
: "application/octet-stream");
response.setContentLength((int) fileName.length());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
+ image_name + "\"");
byte[] bbuf = new byte[BUFSIZE];
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(bbuf)) != -1)) {
outputStream.write(bbuf, 0, length);
}
in.close();
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
}
private byte[] getImage(String filename) {
byte[] result = null;
String fileLocation = filename;
File f = new File(fileLocation);
result = new byte[(int)f.length()];
try {
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
in.read(result);
}
catch(Exception ex) {
System.out.println("GET IMAGE PROBLEM :: "+ex);
ex.printStackTrace();
}
return result;
}
}
```

Put this Jsp inside Web Content

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%
    String imgEncodedStr = request.getParameter("image");
String fileName = request.getParameter("filename");
System.out.println("Filename: "+ fileName);
if(imgEncodedStr != null){
     response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 1);
     byte[] imageByteArray=( ManipulateImage.convertStringtoImage(imgEncodedStr, fileName));//edited

    System.out.println("Inside if");
    out.print("Image upload complete, Please check your directory");
} else{
    System.out.println("Inside else");
    out.print("Image is empty");    
}
%>
```

You can see the uploaded image in the folder given.

Answer (score 1):

this is the sample code to upload image to PHP server :

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if(data != null && data.getData() != null){
                Uri _uri = data.getData();

                if (_uri != null) {
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(_uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
                    Log.w("","image url : "+imageFilePath);
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            UploadFile upload = new UploadFile(UserID.getText().toString(), SignUp.this);
                            upload.uploadFile(imageFilePath);

                        }
                    }).start();
                    innitSignUp();
                }
            }

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
```

////------------ uploadfile code :

```
public class UploadFile {
    private String upLoadServerUri = null;
    String t_name;
    Context context;

    public UploadFile(String filepath, Context context) {
        t_name = filepath;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

        String fileName = sourceFileUri;
        int serverResponseCode = 200;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            try {

                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                        sourceFile);
                upLoadServerUri = context.getString(R.string.httpUploadImage);

                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name='uploaded_file';filename="+"'"
                 + t_name + ".jpg'" + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                // close the streams
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            } // End else block
        }
        return serverResponseCode;
    }



}
```

Comment: the problem that after Icheck again my code, it shows that uri is empty,Why? maybe because I put my link to my php page in intent_gallery.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, SERVER_URL + "uploadFromCamera.php" );? or it's fine like that

Answer (score 0):

I did this tutorial, hope it helps, I use Retrofit to send it to server

```
    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                    "com.example.cedancp.uploadimage",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, MainActivity.RC_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
        }
    }
}


private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
// Create an image file name
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
);

currentImagePath = image.getPath(); //Save current image path to send later to server
return image;
```

}

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {    
    switch (requestCode) {
            case RC_CAPTURE_IMAGE:
                Log.i(TAG, "RESULT CODE " + resultCode);
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if(currentImagePath.length() > 0)
                    sendImageToServer(currentImagePath);
                }else{
                    currentImagePath = "";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error capturing image",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
 default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
    }
}

private void sendImageToServer(String imagePath, final boolean camera){
    final File image = new File(imagePath);
    if(image != null) {
        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), image);
        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", image.getName(), requestFile);
        Call<JsonObject> call = api.uploadImage(body);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                if(response.code() == 200){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Image Uploaded!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if(camera){ //Delete image if it was taken from camera
                        image.delete(); 
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Disclosure: This link is to my own blog.

[Tutorial upload image to server](https://cesarcobop.wordpress.com/2017/10/03/blog-post-title/)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Also, if you are posting a link to your own blog, please [properly self-disclose](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) that fact.

Comment: ok I did not know that, I edited my answer with the code I used @LW001

Comment: @CésarCobo amazing, though please disclose you own the linked website otherwise it's a spam flag which you (and your account) really wouldn't be happy with.

Answer (score 0):

Used this method with pass perimeter and filename must set username.jpg "image format like .png/.jpg"

```
public static String mediaFileUriString(Context context, Uri finalPicUri, 
String filename) {

        try {
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(finalPicUri,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            return picturePath;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return AppConstant.storagePath.getAbsolutePath().concat("/").concat(filename);
        }
    }
```