# upload captured image to server without saving in phone memory

Tags: android, upload, image-capture

I want to upload the captured image to server without saving in phone memory after capturing. Please provide code or example project.

Comment: Check this tutorial: https://trinitytuts.com/capture-image-upload-server-android/

Comment: `I want to upload the captured image` ??? Who and where and how an image was captured? Please tell what you are doing first. After that ask a question.

Comment: `Check this tutorial: ` @Nougat Lover. Wrong tutorial. The image is saved to disk there at capture already.

Comment: see `Bitmap#compress` method

Answer (score 0):

you already have an answer just try this.

[capture image from camera and send it directly to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928101/capture-image-from-camera-and-send-it-directly-to-server)

otherwise try in this link too http://www.java4you.in/2015/09/capture-image-and-upload-to-server-in.html

i hope this will help you what you looking for.

Comment: That post saves the image at capture already. It uses `putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,`. So your Answer will not help at all. It confuses only.

Comment: apologizes..! but the first link may help you from the bitmap only they directly stored the image to server you need not store in memory card

Comment: `they directly stored the image to server`. That code with a http url for EXTRA_OUTPUT  will not work of course. Did you try?

Comment: i need same, i want to upload video to the sever but the problem is without saving on disk. i need to upload directly please help. i am not asking in question because i will look like duplicate